# Re-compile eAccelerator after WHM install

Tags: php, cpanel, whm, recompile, eaccelerator

First Question on Stack overflow so please forgive any stupidity on my part.

I have a problem with my web server at the moment. It has *WHM / cPanel* and I have used WHM many times to adjust settings and to add/remove packages through easyApache.

In easyApache there is the option to install/remove eAccelerator, but there are no config options. eAccelerator is installed and doing its job at the moment but I need to recompile it with the following flag without breaking it.

```
--with-eaccelerator-doc-comment-inclusion
```

I have come accross the following instructions during my googling but they apear to be incomplete, at least for my needs. Please can someone provide a set of instructions that include the above flag so that I can recompile eAccelerator, but without losing anything from eAccelerator that was installed by easyApache.

```
make clean # IMPORTANT!!!
phpize
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call **phpize** you need to reconfigure

> ./configure --with-eaccelerator-doc-comment-inclusion

Comment: Thankyou very much, so I can run the following commands to recompile eAccelerator.

[code]
make clean , 
phpize , 
./configure --with-eaccelerator-doc-comment-inclusion , 
make , 
make install
[code]

Comment: Yes! That should be the way to go